# For immutability, what is the difference between using Object.defineProperty and Object.freeze?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutability

MDN documents [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) as the solution for making a class immutable by preventing any changes to a class after initialization, like so:

```
class ExampleA {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
        Object.freeze(this);
    }
}
```

However, I have seen other people achieve the same effect by using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) like so:

```
class ExampleB {
    constructor(x) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "x", {value: x});
    }
}
```

At first glance, it seems like both ways achieve the same thing, that is being that I want `this.x` to be immutable. On top of that, using `Object.defineProperty()` lets me choose which properties to make immutable instead of making everything immutable like `Object.freeze()` does.

So I need to ask: In terms of achieving immutability, what is the preferred method? Are there any side effects that I might have missed by using `Object.defineProperty()` over `Object.freeze()`?

Comment: Well the most obvious thing seems to be what you already said, that "using Object.defineProperty() lets me choose which properties to make immutable instead of making everything immutable like Object.freeze() does." And also `Object.defineProperty()` can do *other* things that may be useful. (By the way, you understand that even after freezing an object if its properties refer to other objects those objects can still be changed unless they're frozen too?)

Answer (score 3):

Both are totally different tools. `Object.freeze` works shallowly at the `Object` level, whereas `Object.defineProperty` works at the property level. Both can control the mutability of object types, but the latter can do a lot more. Shallowly means, that if a property contains another object type, this object is neither affected by `Object.freeze` nor by `Object.defineProperty`, but remains mutable.

Since you can achieve immutability with both tools only shallowly and deep immutability is expensive, I'd recommend to consider immutability as a policy rather than explicitly enforcing it.